# Is Adobe Air Completely free?

Tags: air, adobe

I need to develop a Desktop application for mac and Windows, Using HTML JqueryMobile and CSS, I Just want to confirm whether Adobe air Completely free for development, And Would Like to know any IDE support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Air is free. However, it may not be what you are looking for if you want to develop your application with HTML, jQuery Mobile, and CSS. The most popular IDE for developing Air applications is Adobe FlashBuilder, which is not free.

There are alternatives to FlashBuilder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974078/alternatives-of-flex-builder

(FlexBuilder was the former name of FlashBuilder)

Comment: Do you mean to say it won't support HTML, jQuery Mobile, and CSS to develope an Standalone application

Comment: Although it will support HTML, jQuery and CSS, Air applications are typically written in ActionScript and MXML. There may be better tools to build you app with those technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free ide Flashdevelop with adobe air sdk that is also free.